# remove part in sentence that starts with /

Tags: notepad++

I have several lines in notepad containing sentence like

```
FONC_VOIR_IDENT_PAT     "00000000010"   //Voir l'identification
```

I want remove the part that starts with `//Voir l'identification`.
How I can do this?

Comment: please elaborate your question

Comment: @user2190482 Please do check my answer

Answer (score 1):

EDITED: Since your question implies you want everything after `/` gone, the regex you want is `/.*`, but I suspect you want the whitespace before the `/` gone as well, in which case you'll want `\s+/.*`. Refer to my original answer if you want to remove parts with `//`.

Also, regex is a valuable thing to learn!

---

You'll want to find `\s+//.*` and replace it with `""`, with Search Mode at Regular expression like this:

[image]

This should remove all comments like the one you listed from your file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below

```
(//Voir l'identification).*$
```

**Explanation:**

`(//Voir l'identification)` is your comment text and `.*` means everything after it. 
`$` is the end of line.

see screen shot of before and after on sample notepad++
**before**
[image]

and **after**
[image]